# React call API depending on Props

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, setstate, react-state-management

The component should fetch new data from an API depending on the value of a Prop. That way - unfortunately - I cannot place the API call in the `componentDidMoun()` method. I need to place it somewhere else to dynamically load it (when the Prop has changed).

I do not know where to place it best practice wise and avoid the problems with the asynchronous side effect through `setState()`.

Let's say I have two components in `App.js`. One which is a list picker where I can pick a country. The country get's passed to another component, which then fetches data from an API and shows the data fetched.

Comment: Use this `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()` where you can check the new props. 
If you want to update the component conditionally you might wanna use `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI You can use `componentDidUpdate` function to make the api call on the basis of condition that new props is not equal to old props.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)
{
  if(this.props[ANY_KEY] ! == prevProps[ANY_KEY]{
    //MAKE THE API CALL HERE AND SET THE STATE IF YOU WANT TO
  }
}
```